# Avoiding reference to schema in queries in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

Being new to C# and postgresql, but not to development and DBs, I'm trying to make the connection from C# .NET to postgresql. I keep running into the same syntax error.

In postgresql I have created a table "`Test`" with one column "`Text`".

To insert data into the table, in pgAdmin 4, I use:

```
insert into public."Test" ("Text") values('It Works!')
```

This works.

Now I try this in C# where I have a working connection to the database:

```
1 NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into Test ("Text") values('It Works!')", postconn);

2 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This gives me a compilation error. Apparently from all the double quotes. 
If I change the command text to:

```
"insert into Test ('Text') values('It Works!')"
```

with single quotes around Text the compiler is happy, but Npgsql gives me a syntax error.

Questions:

1. In pqsql:

   I can see from google that it's possible to get around use the double quotes and the schema reference in psql. 
   But what does it take?
2. In C#:

   Is there a way to construct the string, so that the compiler will accept it?

   - pgAdmin 4 is version 1.0
   - PostgreSQL is version 9.6
   - C# I believe is the most recent version.

Comment: escape with a backslash before the double quote: \"

Comment: yeah ,as  naslund says `NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into Test (\"Text\") values('It Works!')", postconn);`

Comment: it's usually easier to use only lower-case names in postgresql.

Comment: Thanks. I will start using only lower-case

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment about escaping your quotes, you really should use parameters instead of literals.  It may seem like more work initially, but it's:

1. Safer (SQL-injection proof)
2. Easier on the database -- supports compile once, execute many
3. Avoids having crazy SQL statements within C# that have concacts or `string.format` all over the place
4. Avoids the need to single quote literal values and omit quotes for numbers, booleans
5. Strong datatyping means no formatting (dates, for example)

Here is your code with parameters:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into Test (\"Text\") " +
   " values(:TEST)", postconn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TEST", "It Works");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Seems like I made your life harder, but your example was a trivial one.  As you move to complex SQL statements with multiple parameters and different datatypes, you will see the true value.

On a final rant, while there is nothing technically wrong with making case-sensitive field names, it sure does cause nothing but headaches.  Yours is a perfect example.  Without the double quotes around the field "Test", you wouldn't have had an issue to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. I'll switch to parameters in my sql.